# Encoding Error with R

Tags: windows, r, macos, character-encoding

I work in a Mac, but my partner works in Windows 7. Everytime he opens my R script on his computer all the accents show as error. Which encoding should I use to make sure this is not a problem?

Can I set up something on my computer to solve the problem definitely?

Thanks

Comment: I use utf-8 with no problems with my local characters.